# Error cuando intento generar los elementos de Figma en pillow y Tkdesigner

Tags: pillow

hola les muestro que error apareceré cuando intento generar los elementos de Figma, luego de validar el token, URL, carpeta donde guardar, se manda lo siguiente en la terminal.

```
'''

   Creating Element { name: image, type: rectangle }
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matte\Tkinter-Designer\tkdesigner\designer.py", line 21, in to_code
    frame = Frame(f, self.figma_file, self.output_path, self.frameCounter)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\matte\Tkinter-Designer\tkdesigner\figma\frame.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.create_element(child)
  File "C:\Users\matte\Tkinter-Designer\tkdesigner\figma\frame.py", line 78, in create_element
    download_image(image_url, image_path)
  File "C:\Users\matte\Tkinter-Designer\tkdesigner\utils.py", line 23, in download_image
    im = im.resize((im.size[0] // 2, im.size[1] // 2), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'ANTIALIAS'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\matte\Tkinter-Designer\gui\gui.py", line 72, in btn_clicked
    designer.design()
  File "C:\Users\matte\Tkinter-Designer\tkdesigner\designer.py", line 32, in design
    code = self.to_code()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\matte\Tkinter-Designer\tkdesigner\designer.py", line 23, in to_code
    raise Exception("Frame not found in figma file or is empty")
Exception: Frame not found in figma file or is empty

'''
```

según "GPT" el error se debe a:

"El error que estás viendo indica que tu aplicación está tratando de redimensionar una imagen utilizando el método ANTIALIAS en el módulo PIL.Image, pero se produce una excepción de atributo porque la versión de Pillow que estás utilizando no tiene el atributo ANTIALIAS."

ya actualicé Pillow el error persiste

Comment: Te reto a que leas [ask] y hacer el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: @padaleiana XD. MatteoCordero 1 no es necesario retarnos, realmente no vinimos por un reto (si fuera así no creo que vendríamos a este sitio, sino buscarlo en otra parte), intenta modificar el titulo por algo como: " error cuando intento generar los elementos de Figma en pillow y Tkdesigner" o algo que describa tu problema sin retar a nadie ni pedir favor. 2 recomiendo una descripción de lo que intentas hacer y que agregues un poco de código para ver donde esta el error.

Comment: im = im.resize((im.size[0] // 2, im.size[1] // 2), Image.ANTIALIAS);#He revisado un poco la documentación de PIL.Image y no consigo un atributo antialias como dijo chatGPT. Aquí te la dejo para que consigas una alternativa: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto sucede porque usas la constante obsoleta `Image.ANTIALIAS`, fue eliminada en la versión `Pillow 10.0.0`. Para resolverlo tienes dos opciones:

- Usar una constante alterna que cumpla la misma función como `PIL.Image.LANCZOS` o `PIL.Image.Resampling.LANCZOS`:

`im = im.resize((im.size[0] // 2, im.size[1] // 2), Image.LANCZOS);`

- Instalar una versión anterior de `Pillow` como la `9.5.0`:

`pip install Pillow==9.5.0`

> Nota: Esta respuesta es una traducción a otra en inglés:

- [AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'ANTIALIAS'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76616042/attributeerror-module-pil-image-has-no-attribute-antialias)
- [Respuesta a ^](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76616129/15154709)
- [Comentario sobre la segunda opción que dije.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76616042/attributeerror-module-pil-image-has-no-attribute-antialias#:%7E:text=pip%20install%20Pillow%3D%3D9.5.0%20workaround%20for%20old%20code)

Enlaces recomendados:

- [Pil.Image docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html)

Comment: Hola muchas gracias ya se soluciono el error, si lei el recorrido de  bienvenida decia algo como "y si tu título no es interesante, ellos no leerán el resto" quizas exagere pero de igual forma le agradezco que me ayudace con esto Señor Daniel